# What is the license conditions to use Sublime text? Can I use it for free in Ubuntu?

Tags: license, sublime-text

What's the deal with Sublime text (v2 in particular)? I want to use it simply for practice (currently HTML5/CSS). Is it legal to use for free if I'm not using it for financial gain?

Comment: If you are having difficulties installing sublime, I suggest you to ask another question and include the details of what the problems are.

Answer (score 5):

*Sublime* is not *Free Software*, but you can use it without pay any cent.

The condition is that you can use it:

- As *evaluation period*, which does not have a time limitation; or
- With a paid License (per user)

*Source ([official site](http://www.sublimetext.com/)):*

> Sublime Text 2 may be downloaded and evaluated for free, however a
>   license must be purchased for continued use. **There is currently no
>   enforced time limit for the evaluation.**

Here is the [End User License Agreement](http://www.sublimetext.com/eula).

Comment: I interpret this and the question as the opposite. If the OP is using it for "continued use" then they are obliged to pay for it (even if it is possible to use it gratis). I'm not sure what the legal perspective is, and it probably wouldn't be enforced anyway, but beyond the "evaluation" of the _software_, I think the devs are asking for users to buy it.

Comment: Agree with you. But the OP is not using it for "continued use", read what him said: *I want to use it simply for practice*. Anyway, I edited the answer with your advice.

Comment: @Sparhawk you both should remember that I rephrased the question quite a deal, so maybe you should check the revisions before making statements.

Comment: @Lucio I possibly agree with you, and I think the question is ambiguous. I interpreted the "for practice" part as saying the OP wanted to practice HTML5/CSS, not "practise" (test?) the program itself. I'm not sure either way, but +1 to you.

Comment: @Braiam I think your edit maintained the important part of the wording, which is maintained as ambiguous IMO, as my other comment.

Comment: I'm sorry for the ambiguity. I'm very much a beginner (self teaching with the aid of the internet). I want to use Sublime text 2 to write my own html/CSS code and then open the files up in Chromium or Firefox to see if I'm doing it correctly. Basically I want to use Sublime text 2 as a learning tool so I can eventually work as an intern (eventually want to move onto Java and PHP). I suppose I could continue with Text editor but Sublime was suggested to me by a professional/friend.

Comment: @Blacksun That is perfect. You could download Sublime, and see how does it work. If this app is useful for you, then you should consider the acquisition of a license. That is the main idea :-)